# Which method of binding context in React (ES6 classes) is better

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There is no autobinding in React ES6 classes. So developer have two options how he can to bind the context:

1) In the constructor

```
export class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myFunction = this.myFunction.bind(this);
  }
  myFunction() {
    // do something
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this.myFunction}></div>
    );
  }
}
```

2) Inline method

```
export class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  myFunction() {
    // do something
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this.myFunction.bind(this)}></div>
    );
  }
}
```

Which method is more productively working?

Comment: It's more of a style preference, most people use the first method since it cleans up the code a bit

Comment: Agreed with @TylerIguchi ... I prefer the first for a cleaner look, but neither is more "productive"

Comment: If you have multiple listeners you are binding a function to using `.bind(this)`  directly on the element can get tedious and unmanageable at which point it is better to bind in the constructor function. I think its better practice to allows bind in the constructor and go by that standard.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend arrow function.

```js
export class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  myFunction = (e) => {
    // e.preventDefault()
    // do something
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={e => this.myFunction(e)}></div>
    );
  }
}
```

`bind()` is not necessary anymore.

Comment: the problem with this is that a new function is created every time the component re-renders. It would be better to bind in the constructor.

Comment: You're right, is this problem so serious that we can't ignore it? In any case, as you say, we should be careful with the performance.

Answer (score 1):

For handler functions, when they are invoked as ordinary functions, this refers to global object. This will happen when using ECMAScript 6 classes rather than `React.createClass()`, which has auto-binding under the hood. Two approaches can implement the effect of binding as expected. 
First way, use syntax as below to explicitly bind the handler function.

```js
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}
handleChange() {}
```

The other approach is to write the handler property of component in this way, without binding anything.

```js
<MyComponent onChange={() => this.handleChange()}><MyComponent />
```

In such way, the handler will only be called when corresponding event is triggered and at this time, the `this` refers to the component instance, which is what we expect it to refer.

Both approaches can work, deciding which to use is your call.